# HDD benchmark, custom QD?

Tags: hard-drive

Is there any benchmark allowing me to set custom QD? All of them are QD=1 or QD=32. I want to test other values, like QD=64 or QD=16.

Comment: What do you mean by QD?

Comment: queue depth, see here: http://www.tweaktown.com/articles/5788

Comment: It may be helpful to include that in your question so people don't have to ask more questions. Googling "HDD QD" only returns this question.